# How to use shared module between two binaries in a Cargo package?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

My project has a client and a server binary. So my `Cargo.toml` looks something like

```ini
[[bin]]
name = "server"
path = "src/server/mod.rs"

[[bin]]
name = "client"
path = "src/client.rs"
```

My file structure looks something like:

```
.
├── client.rs
├── server
│   ├── something.rs
│   └── mod.rs
└── shared
    ├── mod.rs
    └── something2.rs
```

What I want to do is use anything from `shared` in `server/mod.rs`. To do that I tried to have a `mod shared` and `use crate::shared` in the `server/mod.rs` but I got the error "no 'shared' in the root" (It is only looking in `shared/`). I don't have a `main.rs` where I could properly declare the modules.

So another thing I tried was using `server.rs` instead of `server/mod.rs`. This worked partially, as I now can declare mod shared. However, I cannot access anything in `server/something.rs` anymore. Is there any way to get the `server.rs` see the contents of `server/` or is there a way to make `server/mod.rs` see the contents of a neighboring module without having a top level `main.rs`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [the `#[path]` attribute](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/modules.html#the-path-attribute):

```rust
#[path = "../shared/mod.rs"]
mod shared;
```

But the proper way is to have a library, in addition to `client` and `server`, and make both depend on it.

Comment: Make a library as a completely new project or is there a different way to properly create a library for this project scope?

Comment: @Pinko In one package, you can have as many binaries as you want and a single library. https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/cargo-targets.html#configuring-a-target.